# Apply random color to UI element and keep track of it within the store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

**I have a React Redux web app** 

In List of items I want to generate a random color for each item, 
at the **first** time
 and then **keep** it with the same color.
I’m fetching the contacts from a server and then store them in redux store . More contacts can be fetched later on users scroll

**My problem is to decide where to do the random action:**

- If I do it in the component class 
  It will cause render multiple
  times, and will cause an error
- I can do it in the action that fetches the list data, but it will
  **make** the action to **know** about the colors(array) in the ui.

React List sample

```js
function render() {
    const { contacts } = this.props;
    const contacts = mailContacts.map(({
      id,name, snippet, colorIndex
    }) => {
      const index;
      if(colorIndex == undefined) {
        index = myRandom(colorsCount);
        // This is bad solution it rerendes ui 
        // Too much times and causes error
        this.props.saveRandomColor(id, colorIndex);
      } else {
        index = colorIndex;
      }
      contacts.map(contact => {
        return (
          <Contact
            className="contact"
            key={name}
            snippet={snippet}
            colorIndex={index}
          />
        );
      })
    });
  }
```

Comment: If you know how many items you are going to render, predetermine the colours and store the values in your redux store prior to doing any rendering i.e. set up the initial state first.

Comment: So you are suggesting to do this in the action ?

Comment: It depends how your app works. If your app starts with contacts then I'd predetermine their colours before anything is rendered. Hence to do this I'd setup the store appropriately. If you click on something to add a new contact, yes, I'd dispatch an action and then generate the colour (and then update the state for this new item) in the redux reducer.

Comment: My app fetches the data from a server

Comment: I’m thinking about moving it to the action that fetches the data ,my only concern is the design . It forces the action to know about the ui colors or how many colors are there .

Comment: Ok, so when your app starts I'd fetch the data from the server, then persist that data in your Redux store whilst generating the random colours. When your app then renders the data from the store it will have the colours it will need. My point above regarding new contacts would still be apt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205261/discussion-between-ben-smith-and-rami-loiferman).

Answer (score 0):

You may store binding of unique contact id to randomly generated color within your global state and append that to color map upon initial render of `ContactCard` component.

After that your corresponding `ContactCard` components will be rendered based on their id and that global color map:

```js
//dependencies
const { useEffect } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM,
      { createStore } = Redux,
      { connect, Provider } = ReactRedux
      
//random color function
const randomColor = () => {
  const rndHex = () => (0|Math.random()*255).toString(16).padStart(2,'0')
  return `#${[...Array(3)].map(rndHex).join('')}`
}
      
//default state with empty contact list color map, app reducer and store
const defaultState = {contactsColors: []},
      appReducer = (state=defaultState, action) => {
        switch(action.type){
          case 'APPEND_COLOR_BINDING' : {
            const { contactId } = action,
                  { contactsColors } = state
            contactsColors.push({id:contactId,color:randomColor()})
            return {...state, contactsColors}
          }
          default: return state
        }
      },
      store = createStore(appReducer)
      
//contact card ui component
const ContactCard = ({name,color,onInitialRender}) => {
  useEffect(onInitialRender,[])
  return (
      <div>
        <div style={{backgroundColor:color,border:'1px solid black',width:10,height:10,margin:'auto 2px',display:'inline-block'}}></div>
        <div style={{display:'inline-block'}}>{name}</div>
      </div>
    )
}
//contact card container, retrieving color map from store with fallback to white
const mapStateToProps = ({contactsColors},{id}) => ({
        color: (contactsColors.find(item => item.id == id)||{color:'white'}).color
      }),
      mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, {id}) => ({
        onInitialRender: () => dispatch({type:'APPEND_COLOR_BINDING',contactId:id})
      }),
      ContactCardContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ContactCard)
//contact cards wrapper, having entire contact list within its params
const ContactList = ({contacts}) => (
  <div>
    {contacts.map(({id,name},key) => <ContactCardContainer {...{key,id,name}} />)}
  </div>
)
//draw contact list with arbitrary source array
render (
  <Provider store={store}>
  <ContactList contacts={[
    {id: 1, name: 'Steve Rogers'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Tony Stark'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Thor Odinsson'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Bruce Banner'}
  ]} />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.1.3/react-redux.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: My case is a little different . I’m fetching contacts from server on start and when user scroll I’m fetching more .